# Nginx conf exclude directory from location ~* \.(?:js)$

Tags: nginx

How can I exclude all URLs with a directory called dynamic in the following location block:

```
location ~* \.(?:js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Here's the entire config, most of this comes from herokus php nginx buildpack
http://pastebin.com/xQ4BDtwr
( stackex won't let me post "mostly code" )

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following location:

```
location /path/to/dynamic/ {
    location ~* \.js$ {internal;}
}
```

The key is to override the `~* \.(?:js)$` regex location with a prefix location. Then you don't have to worry about where it appears in your config.

It could be solved with another regex location `~ /dynamic/.*\.js$ {internal;}`, but then you would need to be sure it *always* comes before the `~* \.(?:js)$` location; another problem waiting to happen when your config grows.